# Send dynamicaly generated selects via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have this:

```
<? foreach ($atributes as $key => $value) { ?>
    <select size="10" id="attr_id_<?=$value['id']?>">
        <? foreach ($value['attrs'] as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$value['value_id']?>" ><?=$value['name']?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
<? } ?>
```

I need to send those selected options via ajax to a controller.

I usually send data to controllers like these:

```
function save_values() {
    $.post("/dir/page.php",
        {
            api:"update_values",
            attr_id:attr_id,
            value_id:value_id,
    },
    function(data){

    });
}
```

And having the controller listen to the post request like these:

```
if($this->input->get_post('api') == "update_values") {
    $attr_id = $this->input->get_post('attr_id');
    ....
```

I will like to have all the select ID value and option value relationated to each other, like this:

```
array
    (
        'attr_id_XX' => 'XX',
        'attr_id_XX' => 'XX,
    );
```

It doesn't need to be an array, but I need to process those in a relational way, so I can save each attr_id with the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the selects in a form and use jQuery's serialize function.

Consider the following:

(Note that the name attribute must be present on the selects)

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select name="attr1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="attr2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="attr3">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = '';   // ...

        $.ajax(url, {
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#myForm').serialize()
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am will search for how CodeIgniter process the values that way. Will research about it and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for your JS function

```
function save_values() {
    var select_data = {'api': 'update_values', 'value_id': value_id};
    $('select').each(function() {
        select_data[$(this).attr("id")] =  $(this).find(":selected").attr('value');
    });
    $.post("/dir/page.php", select_data,
    function(data){

    });
}
```

Comment: I am trying this way. Sorry for the delay, will report back/update the post soon. Thanks!